# creating a timed slider with buttons that affect text and images in different parts of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button, slider

I am using this tutorial to create a fading slider gallery for my website: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtYP_eSVKfs&list=UUWxB7V9weF702avKxXESdvw&index=5

I have the images looping in a gallery with previous and next arrows to navigate the gallery and added individual buttons between the next and previous arrows to go to separate pictures, but I'm having trouble with text that I want to describe each image.  The text is in a separate column, and cycles through like the images do, but when I click on the navigation buttons the text keeps scrolling from where it was at instead of moving to a the text that corresponds to the image.

here is the the code with alt tabs on JSFiddle, but it doesn't seem to want to function.

http://jsfiddle.net/agwlora/tne3rkse/3/

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
    <td class="opacBack" valign="top" width="200px">
        <table width="75%" border="0" cellspacing="5px">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>work</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" height="475px" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="bottom">
                    <div id="textslide">1 text</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td width="800px">
        <div align="center" id="slider">
            <img id="1" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/01.jpg" alt="1" />
            <img id="2" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/02.jpg" alt="2" />
            <img id="3" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/03.jpg" alt="3" />
            <img id="4" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/04.jpg" alt="4" />
            <img id="5" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/05.jpg" alt="5" />
            <img id="6" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/06.jpg" alt="6" />
            <img id="7" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/07.jpg" alt="7" />
            <img id="8" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/08.jpg" alt="8" />
            <img id="9" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/09.jpg" alt="9" />
            <img id="10" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/10.jpg" alt="10" />
            <img id="11" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/12.jpg" alt="11" />
            <img id="12" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/13.jpg" alt="12" />
            <img id="13" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/14.jpg" alt="13" />
            <img id="14" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/15.jpg" alt="14" />
            <img id="15" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/16.jpg" alt="15" />
            <img id="16" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/17.jpg" alt="16" />
            <img id="17" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/18.jpg" alt="17" />
            <img id="18" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/19.jpg" alt="18" />
            <img id="19" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/20.jpg" alt="19" />
            <img id="20" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/21.jpg" alt="20" />
            <img id="21" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/22.jpg" alt="21" />
            <img id="22" src="images/gallery/Commercial/for_site/23.jpg" alt="22" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <div align="center">
<a id="prev" href="#" onclick="prev(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/arrow_previous.png"  </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo1(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="1" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo2(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="2" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo3(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="3" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo4(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="4" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo5(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="5" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo6(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="6" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo7(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="7" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo8(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="8" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo9(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="9" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo10(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="10" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo11(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="11" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo12(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="12" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo13(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="13" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo14(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="14" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo15(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="15" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo16(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="16" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo17(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="17" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo18(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="18" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo19(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="19" />  </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo20(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="20" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo21(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="21" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="goTo22(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/button_thumbnail.png" alt="22" /> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="next(); return flase"><img src="images/gallery/buttons/arrow_next.png" /> </a>

        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I apologize for the messiness, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, in the JavaScript I used the sliderInt-1 instead of the i for the quotes and included it in the function next(), prev() etc etc a la:

```
function prev(){
    newSlide=sliderInt-1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
    $("#textslide").html(quotes[sliderInt-1]);
}
```

inside of the startSlider, next(), prev(), and goto##(), functions